# Dropdown menu not floating in a flex row

Tags: html, css

I have an accordion where it has a flex-row textbox and it has icons on its right.
I need to add the menu positioned as shown in the image below

[image]

My code is here

```html
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    .accordion {
      margin: 30px;
    }
    
    .accordion-button.collapsed {
      border-bottom: #ccc 1px solid
    }
    
    .accordion-body {
      border-left: #673ab744 1px solid;
      border-bottom: #673ab744 1px solid;
      border-right: #673ab744 1px solid
    }
    
    .accordion-button {
      display: inline!important
    }
    
    .flx-row {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: space-between;
    }
  </style>
  <script src="/scripts/snippet-javascript-console.min.js?v=1"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <script src="/scripts/snippet-javascript-console.min.js?v=1"></script>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-Zenh87qX5JnK2Jl0vWa8Ck2rdkQ2Bzep5IDxbcnCeuOxjzrPF/et3URy9Bv1WTRi" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-OERcA2EqjJCMA+/3y+gxIOqMEjwtxJY7qPCqsdltbNJuaOe923+mo//f6V8Qbsw3" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Material+Symbols+Outlined:opsz,wght,FILL,GRAD@48,400,0,0">

  <div class="accordion accordion-flush" id="accordionFlushExample">
    <div class="accordion-item">
      <h2 class="accordion-header" id="flush-headingOne">
        <button class="accordion-button collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#flush-collapseOne" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="flush-collapseOne">
      
        <div class="flx-row">          
          <div>
            <input type="textbox" value="Accordion Item #1">
          </div>
          <div>
          

        <div class="btn-group">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm dropdown-toggle" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false"> More </button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-lg-end" style="">
          <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Export</a></li>
          <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Duplicate</a></li>
          <li><a class="dropdown-item tdelete" href="#">Delete</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <span class="wcopy material-symbols-outlined text-primary">content_copy</span>
    <span class="wdelete material-symbols-outlined text-primary">delete</span>





  </div>
  </div>

  <br><span>Desc goes here</span><br><span>Desc goes here</span>

  </button>
  </h2>
  <div id="flush-collapseOne" class="accordion-collapse collapse" aria-labelledby="flush-headingOne" data-bs-parent="#accordionFlushExample">
    <div class="accordion-body">Placeholder content for this accordion, which is intended to demonstrate the <code>.accordion-flush</code> class. This is the first item's accordion body.</div>
  </div>
  </div>
  <div class="accordion-item">
    <h2 class="accordion-header" id="flush-headingTwo">
      <button class="accordion-button collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#flush-collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="flush-collapseTwo">
          Accordion Item #2
      </button>
    </h2>
    <div id="flush-collapseTwo" class="accordion-collapse collapse" aria-labelledby="flush-headingTwo" data-bs-parent="#accordionFlushExample">
      <div class="accordion-body">Placeholder content for this accordion, which is intended to demonstrate the <code>.accordion-flush</code> class. This is the second item's accordion body. Let's imagine this being filled with some actual content.</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>

  <div class="as-console-wrapper">
    <div class="as-console"></div>
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(".wdelete").off().on('click', function(event) {
      if (confirm(`Are you sure to delete the workflow ${$(this).prev().parent().prev().val()}?`) == true) {
        $(this).closest('.accordion-item').remove();
      }
      event.preventDefault();
      event.stopPropagation();
    });
  </script>

  <div class="as-console-wrapper">
    <div class="as-console"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="as-console-wrapper">
    <div class="as-console"></div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Listen you may not refer to your problem's answer
Note if your question was anything else plz let me know

Just have a container div then tell your div that has two children
One is left(your items and options)
And right hand your inputs such dropdown list and that delete icon
So just forget about the flex-row class.
Put your entire code shown in the question in a div with the style of =

```
display:flex;
```

Then
Have two (div)s
First
div (your items #item ...) with syle of =

```
flex:80%;
```

And div (drop down list and delete icon ...) with style of =

```
flex:20%;
```

So:

```
<div class='father-of-two-children'>
 <div class='left-hand-div'>
  My options ...#items..
 </div>
 <div class='right-hand-div'>
  delete icon ...dropdown list...
  It is based on your periority of 
  your items and inputs.they will 
  appear in order. 
 </div>
</div>
<style>
 .father-of-two-children{
   display:flex;
  }
 .left-hand-div{
   flex:80%;
 }
 .right-hand-div{
   flex:20%;
 }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

The code I presented for you previously *(as below)* works perfectly fine. You can list any element you wish to be flex aligned in the row.

The issue you are having is the code you are using is not semantically correct. For example: you have buttons nested within buttons. A button should be the final interactable element in a hierarchy. I recommend you change the accordion interaction to simple a `div`.

Once you have refactored your code, you should be able to align items easily within a 2-dimensional flex array using `align-items`.

You may wish to try and get a better understanding of flex before moving forward.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex

```css
.pad {
  padding: 10px;
}

.flx-row {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-Zenh87qX5JnK2Jl0vWa8Ck2rdkQ2Bzep5IDxbcnCeuOxjzrPF/et3URy9Bv1WTRi" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-OERcA2EqjJCMA+/3y+gxIOqMEjwtxJY7qPCqsdltbNJuaOe923+mo//f6V8Qbsw3" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Material+Symbols+Outlined:opsz,wght,FILL,GRAD@48,400,0,0">


<div class="flx-row pad">

  <div>
    <input type="textbox" value="Accordion Item #1" />
  </div>

  <div class="btn-group">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm dropdown-toggle" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false"> More </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-lg-end" style="">
      <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Export</a></li>
      <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Duplicate</a></li>
      <li><a class="dropdown-item tdelete" href="#">Delete</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div>
    <span class="wcopy material-symbols-outlined text-primary">content_copy</span>
    <span class="wdelete material-symbols-outlined text-primary">delete</span>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Definitley not the final result he's looking for I think.

Answer (score -1):

Take your 'Span Tags' for Icon Inside div of class 'btn-group' then icons will automatically come next to the drop down

```
    <div class="btn-group">

        <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm dropdown-toggle" data-bs- 
            toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false"> More </button>

        <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-lg-end">
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Export</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Duplicate</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item tdelete" href="#">Delete</a></li>
        </ul>

           <span class="wcopy material-symbols-outlined text- 
                 primary">content_copy</span>
          <span class="wdelete material-symbols-outlined text- 
            primary">delete</span>

    </div>
```

Comment: Thanks, Could you please post the whole snippet? This solution isnt working for me